# torch.cuda.is_available() return True outside project, return False inside project

Tags: python, pytorch

I installed pytorch with cuda support using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge` command. But, when I run my project codes, the `torch.cuda.is_available()' returns False and causes an error. But, when I check outside the project (in the same environment) it returns True. I add the screenshot below.

> Specs: Windows 10, Python 3.9.6, Pytorch 1.9.0, CUDA 11.1

Do you have any idea what causes this error? How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: *"when I check outside the project"*, how do you check?

Comment: How are you running "inside the project"? Do you use PyCharm or Jupyter, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused because your project is not using the same Python kernel.
I suggest testing to see if torch.cuda.is_available() return False when running `>> python3` instead of just `>> python` in your terminal.

If it does return False, then I suggest to use conda to create a new empty environment. Then in that environment, run that same conda installation line first. Check to see if `>> python3`  shows that `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns True. Then check if it works with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I probably had the same problem.
I was running the following block of code in debug mode using PyCharm and  `torch.cuda.is_available()` returned False. However, using the same virtual environment in the terminal, with the same interpreter, resulted in the same command returning True.

[image]

After googling it, I stumbled upon the solution in a [github repo](https://github.com/jackaduma/CycleGAN-VC2/issues/9) about a similar issue.
Eventually, I just commented out line 33 in my code and solved the problem.